# Web API XML Deserialization : Node with multiple child nodes with same tag name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API using Visual Studio 2015.
My request xml contains child nodes with the same tag name.

```
<TestData>
   <TestChild>
      <input>
       <name ="Test1"/>
       <value="DUMMY VALUE1"/>
      </input>
      <input>
       <name ="Test1"/>
       <value="DUMMY VALUE1"/>
      </input>
      <input>
       <name ="Test1"/>
       <value="DUMMY VALUE1"/>
      </input>
 </TestChild>
</TestData>
```

I've added the XRoot and the XElement attribute to the .net c# object as below :

```
    [XmlRoot]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public TestChild TestChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestChild
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public input[] input { get; set; }
    }

    public class input
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

But the sample xml generated through the above code looks a bit different. It adds a parent **input** tag and then within that multiple input tags are being added. I need the xml to look as the one shared above.

```
<TestData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TestChild>
    <input>
      <input>
        <name>sample string 1</name>
        <value>sample string 2</value>
      </input>
      <input>
        <name>sample string 1</name>
        <value>sample string 2</value>
      </input>
    </input>
  </TestChild>
</TestData>
```

I have tried setting

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

but this doesn't help either.
I am new to Web API and any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is getting rid of the `TestChild` class and adding `public input[] TestChild` to `TestData` an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the **TestChild property** but remove the **TestChild Class**.
Try like this :

```
    [XmlRoot]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public input[] TestChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class input
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```